# Method X has no supported translation to SQL - booleans and datetime

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Has anyone a suggestion of how to make this function supported by LINQ to SQL?

```
public bool IsEnabled()
{
    return !this.Disabled && 
           ((!this.EnabledFrom.HasValue || this.EnabledFrom < DateTime.Now) && 
            (!this.EnabledTo.HasValue || this.EnabledTo > DateTime.Now));
}
```

Disabled is a bool, EnabledFrom and EnabledTo is DateTime?  and all database fields.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any LINQ in the code you showed. I doubt this is the code causing your error.

Comment: Example of query (part of it) using IsEnabled;
query = query.Where(a => a.PageMeta.Hidden == !visible && a.PageMeta.IsEnabled() == visible);

Comment: The problem is probably that it tries to find IsEnabled in SQL. Move the logic from IsEnabled directly to the linq query.

Comment: What is the SQL statement that Linq2Sql should convert your code to?  What is PageMeta?  And what does 'this' refer to in your IsEnabled method?

Comment: Make it return an expression.

Comment: the query is on a linq object, which has PageMeta as a EntityRef

Comment: i have not succeeded making an express that I can use through the EntityRef - is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Make your `IsEnabled` method return an expression.

See here: http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/09/05/Calling+Custom+Methods+In+LINQtoSQL.aspx

Something like below (untested):

```
static Expression<Func<Account, bool>> IsEnabled = a =>
    !a.Disabled && 
    ((!a.EnabledFrom.HasValue || a.EnabledFrom < DateTime.Now) && 
     (!a.EnabledTo.HasValue || a.EnabledTo > DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: Looks great! But do you know how I can access IsEnabled through a EntityRef: .Where(a => a.Account.IsEnabled) <- this does not work

Comment: .Where will execute on the object in the query, but "Account" is a EntityRef on the objects. This will work: query.Select(a => a.Account).Where(IsEnabled)  - but then I only get Accounts in return, I need the original objects

Comment: Then change IsEnabled to not use `Account` and instead use the type of `a`.

Comment: a can be different kinds of objects that has Account as EntityRef. So i wanted a dynamic solution.. I'm not being easy ;)

Comment: Hmm, maybe make IsEnabled a generic function? Otherwise i'm out of ideas.