# Linq to SQL Calculated property based on 2 bools

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm adding some properties to my partial classes created by the L2S generator.
I'm trying to create an "Available" Boolean property based on 2 other properties. "Enabled" and "Confirmed"
I did simply have

```
    public Boolean Available
    {
        get
        {
            return (Enabled && Confirmed);
        }
    }
```

However when running this, it throws the "No translation to SQL" error.

How can I create this property without needing to always check "Enabled" and "Confirmed" when querying the data context?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it to return an expression!
Please see: http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/09/05/Calling+Custom+Methods+In+LINQtoSQL.aspx

Also this post could be of help: 
[Method X has no supported translation to SQL - booleans and datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995892/method-x-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql-booleans-and-datetime)